# How to align tick labels when numbers have superscript in it in maptlotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am generating a figure where the x-axis is set to a base-10 log scale and I want the labels to be plain numbers (1, 10, 100) for short numbers and abbreviated with a superscript when too long ($10^{3}$, $10^{4}$).

The problem is that the bounding box differs between plain text and math text with superscript.Specifically, there is extra white space between the bottom of the text and the bottom edge of the bounding box for the superscript notation.

So when I try to align the labels (text + bbox) with `set_ha('bottom')`, the bboxs are aligned correctly but the texts are not because of the extra white space in the math text labels.

The issue seems somewhat related to this one [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4335/) except that in my case, I am dealing with math and non-math notations behaving differently.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

def setup(ax):
    """Only show bottom axis"""
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.NullLocator())

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 1))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

setup(ax)

ticklabels = [r'0', r'10', r'$100$', r'$10^3$', r'$10^4$', r'$10^5$']
ax.set_xticklabels(ticklabels, fontdict=dict(fontsize=11))

# align and move labels
for label in ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels():
    # uncomment to see the extra white space
    # below labels with superscript notation
    # label.set_bbox(dict(edgecolor='red', facecolor='none', pad=0))
    label.set_va('bottom')
    label.set_y(-.14)
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pCGo.jpg) is a figure showing how I'd like my labels aligned.

Is there a way to set the bbox such that the space below the labels is the same between the two notations?

Comment: Please explain what behavior you expect? Either the red boxes can be aligned at the top edges of the boxes, or at the bottom. Your code aligns them at the bottom edge, if you don't use your for loop, they are aligned at the top edges. What third behavior do you expect. Please include some hand drawn figure to explain the problem

Comment: Thanks for answering @Sheldore, I edited my post accordingly. I think the problem is not the alignment but it is that my the bboxes are different whether I am using plain text or math text with superscript. Because of that, the alignment looks weird because the text are not aligned. Maybe there is a way to align the text labels at the bottom of the bbox?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to add the following code at the top of the script to render all the texts with latex to have consistent bounding boxes:

```py
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text', usetex=True)
```